# Exception while performing a SOAP request using suds in python

Tags: soap-client, python-2.6, suds

I am accessing our jira system to get some information through SOAP. They updated the jira system lately and I started seeing some problems. The problem is very well known but I couldn't wrap head around the solution which was posted.

File "C:\CRMAPPS\APPS\PYTHON~1\lib\xml\sax\handler.py", line 38, in fatalError
    raise exception
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: :756:14: no element found

Query function – 
JQLStr = """ project=%s and ( summary ~ "\"%s"" OR description ~ "\"%s"" ) and key >= %s ORDER BY key ASC"""%(self.proj, buildID, buildID, ind)

issues = self.client.service.getIssuesFromJqlSearch (self.auth , JQLStr , 500)

It use to work properly with a quick and dirty fix I had, changing the 500 results to 1.
issues = self.client.service.getIssuesFromJqlSearch (self.auth , JQLStr , 1)

But pretty lately It's not return me the proper number tickets. I wanted to know If I need to update SUDS / Python or Complain to IT people responsible to keep Jira up and Running.

I am responsible for more than 10 reporting scripts which are currently functionally failing or crashing due to above 2 reasons.. Using a different soap client is not something I can afford with such a tight schedule..

Answer (score 0):

This may not exactly be a suds issue. Could you pasted your full code?

Have you validate that the same Service call returns the results when you use a Tool (SOAPUI may be) to invoke the service?